# Verify the emails of all users in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just added email verification to my app, but I don't want to make my beta testers verify their email. For complicated reasons, some of my beta testers would not be able to verify their email or make a new account if I were to release this new build. Is there a way that I can verify the emails of all of my beta tester accounts in Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the admin SDK and and update the users as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UpdateRequest.html via the `emailVerified` field.

I would suggest that you use a cloud function for this that you can trigger when you release a new version.

You will need to store a list of all the associated email addresses and then run your function whenever you need to verify them.